# How do I execute php with different version through phpbrew

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-artisan, phpbrew

Currently I am working on a laravel project that uses some cron jobs to process data.

The default php version on this server is `7.0.7`. However this project runs on php `5.6.6` through phpbrew.

When I execute a script inside my project folder through laravel artisan, `phpinfo()` returns php version `5.6.6`. When my cron job executes the exact same command it returns version `7.0.7`.

Is it possible to say to my cron to use a different php version through phpbrew? How would it look like?

My cron job looks like:

`00 12 * * * php /projectfolder/artisan execute:command`

Comment: You need set full path to binary php file for example `/usr/bin/php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change your cron to link the absolute path of the php binary you want to use.
`00 12 * * * /path/to/bin/that/is/used/by/app/php /projectfolder/artisan execute:command`

Also, if this is L5.1 or greater, check out task scheduling https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling

Comment: You are my heroes @moak (and Naumov) :) It also totally makes sence and I don't know why I did not think about that earlier. Thanks.